# socket.io, Node.js Как понять, что у пользователя сейчас открыт чат, чтобы отмечать сообщений прочитанными?

Tags: node.js, api, websocket, backend, socket.io

Буду благодарен за помощь. Хотелось бы понять правильную практику использования сокетов в чате Node.js и socket.io. А именно есть три вопроса на которые я так и не нашел ответа. Например

1. userA и userB находятся в чате и мне нужно отмечать сообщения прочтенными, если userA отправляет userB. Есть такая идея. Каждый раз, когда userA открывает чат, делаю sockee event с chatId и в redis записываю: userId, chatId.
2. Мне нужно знать, когда user онлайн или оффлайн. Для этого я добавил в таблицу user lastActivity Datetime. Есть проблема с ее обновлением. На текущий момент я сделал так:

```html
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    let lastActivity = Date.now();
    await database.set(userId, lastActivity); # каждый request api обновляет поле в таблице
    next();
});
```

Но мне кажется, что каждый запрос вызывающий обновление - плохая практика.

С другой стороны я мог бы при подключении и отключении к сокетам добавить обновление lastAcitviy, но мне кажется это не лучшее решение в плане нагрузки.

```html
socket.on(`connect`, () => {
    let lastActivity = Date.now();
    await database.set(userId, lastActivity);
    join(userId) # подписываюсь на события
}); 

socket.on(`disconnect`, () => {
    leave(userId) # отписываюсь  (понятно, могут быть таймауты и прочие вещи
});
```

3. При открытии чата, мне нужно сразу же отобразить 15 сообщений используя пагинацию. Можно реализовать через api get, но тогда пройдет какое-то время перед их отображением пока выполниться запрос. Можно через сокеты запросить (но маловероятно, что это так правильно). Возможно с массивом чатов и передавать previewMessages, где будет какое-то количество сообщений. Т.е. при открытии чата, не нужно ничего подгружать.

Comment: 1) Когда одному из участников приходит сообщение в чат, можно сделать проверку на клиенте и послать ивент с последнем увиденным сообщением, соответственно все сообщения ниже этого id будут автоматом прочитаны, либо же на клиенте получать айдишники всех сообщений которые были на экране и отправлять ивент на прочтение. 2) Можно в редисе хранить онлайн участника и он удалится от туда автоматически, в базу можно писать последнее посещение участника когда он удалится из редиса, отловить ивент на удаление участника и записать в базу когда последний раз он был в сети

Comment: 3) если у вас чат загружается на клиенте, то можно послать запрос или если у вас нет проблем с сокетами, сразу отдать пачку первичных сообщений. Если чат загружается вместе с страницей, то можно сразу отдать сообщения на стороне сервера вместе с всем сайтом или пакетом который вы предоставляете. А так, просто при подключении и успешной авторизации в сокете сразу отдавать пачку сообщений неплохой вариант

Comment: @MoloF спасибо большое. Очень помогли с решением)

Comment: 1.В первом и втором случае, клиенту надо понимать, когда отправлять  последний id или массив id-в. Это хороший вариант, но здесть какой-то timeout должен быть, потому что на каждое последнее сообщение лочиться вряд ли правильно.   Мне кажется, проблему бы решило понимание, что сейчас собеседник в чате. Отправляю новое сообщение и проверяю checkIsChatReсeiver и сразу же в БД помещаю сообщение как прочитано.

Comment: Сначала вы должны сделать рабочий вариант и только потом его оптимизировать, без большого опыта не сделать сразу хорошее и рабочее приложение, сделайте так, чтобы оно работало, а дальше оптимизируйте. Проблема разработки вообще хоть каких-то систем и заключается в том, что хочется сделать идеально, а в итоге тратится очень много времени и результата не удается достичь. Что будет если участник беседы прокрутит чат вверх, как сервер обработает этот кейс? Не создавайте себе дополнительные проблемы, сделайте самый простой на ваше усмотрение вариант!